# Resources for interesting facts about biology

Tags: general-biology

Are there resources for interesting or fun facts about biology, for example:

- fastest animal/bird/insect
- largest organ in human body
- largest virus
- largest genome
- largest de novo synthesized genome
- largest protein
- longest experiment done so far
- most expensive experiment done so far
- biggest discovery by luck
- ...

You get the idea. It would be nice if these is a curated "database" for all these interesting facts that might be fascinating to lay people as well.

Comment: Well I think that jarlemag's answer is pretty good and important for the community. Too bad that others can't post other sources if they stumble upon them. I actually disagree that the answer will be opinion-based, as I would expect people to provide resources, not what they would consider to be "fun or important". If you have any suggestions how to change my question to reflect this, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you find the content interesting or not I can't say, but you might want to check out the [BioNumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu) database. It has a category for ["Amazing bionumbers"](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?task=searchbyamaz) and a ["BioNumber of the Month"](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/plants/Milo/index.php?page_name=BioNumberOfTheMonth) section.

Comment: That's cool! Yeah, that's what I am talking about. And this is not just for me, but for the community. So whatever I don't find interesting, I am sure others will :) Your 'BioNumbers" link is not working.